# Я читаю книгу *** и встретился с такой проблемой, у меня 5.0.0, за счет этого изменились методы. Вот мой код, я делаю не так?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
        var Loc = mongoose.model('Location');

        var theEarth = (function() {
            var earthRadius = 6371; // km, miles is 3959

            var getDistanceFromRads = function(rads) {
                return parseFloat(rads * earthRadius);
            };

            var getRadsFromDistance = function(distance) {
                return parseFloat(distance / earthRadius);
            };

            return {
                getDistanceFromRads: getDistanceFromRads,
                getRadsFromDistance: getRadsFromDistance
            };
        })();

    module.exports.locationsListByDistance = function(req, res) {
        var lng = parseFloat(req.query.lng);
        console.log("gaasdasdsa" + req.query.lng);
        console.log(req.query.lat);
        var lat = parseFloat(req.query.lat);
        var maxDistance = parseFloat(req.query.maxDistance);

        if ((!lng && lng!==0) || (!lat && lat!==0) || ! maxDistance) {
            console.log('locationsListByDistance missing params');
            sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
                "message": "lng, lat and maxDistance query parameters are all required"
            });
            return;
        }
        Loc.aggregate(
            [
                {
                    $geoNear: {
                        near: {
                            type: "Point",
                            coordinates: [ -0.9690884, 51.455041 ]
                        },
                        key: "location",
                        distanceField: "dist.calculated",
                        query: { "category": "Stadiums" }
                    }
                },
                function(err, results, stats) {
                    var locations;
                    console.log('Geo Results', results);
                    console.log('Geo stats', stats);
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('geoNear error:', err);
                        sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
                    } else {
                        locations = buildLocationList(req, res, results, stats);
                        sendJSONresponse(res, 200, locations);
                    }
                }
            ]);

    };



var buildLocationList = function(req, res, results, stats) {
    var locations = [];
    results.forEach(function(doc) {
        locations.push({
            distance: theEarth.getDistanceFromRads(doc.dis),
            name: doc.obj.name,
            address: doc.obj.address,
            rating: doc.obj.rating,
            facilities: doc.obj.facilities,
            _id: doc.obj._id
        });
    });
    return locations;
};



----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С какой проблемой? Вы забыли написать.

Comment: Если версия mongoose 4 и более, naemCollection.geoNear()  не работает

Comment: Документация говорит, что убрали только команду geoNear. Агрегация `$geoNear` все еще работает https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#pipe._S_geoNear

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте документацию по этому методу [db.aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.aggregate/)

Ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
Loc.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [ -0.9690884, 51.455041 ]
            },
            key: "location",
            distanceField: "dist.calculated",
            query: { "category": "Stadiums" }
        }
    }
], function(err, results) {
    // что-то делаем с результатом
});
```

Третьего параметра в callback-функции нет. Только ошибка и результат в виде массива